# can't get data from json even getting a response on the console

Tags: javascript, php, json, firebird

I've been trying to send this information to the js.

```
$statement = ibase_prepare($sql);
    $query = ibase_execute($statement);

while ($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
    echo json_encode($data);
```

However, when I try to, I get the response, but I can't get the data.

```
$('document').ready(function (){

 $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "../Dashboard/php/chart.php",
    dataType: "json",
    sucess: function (data){
   
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Remove JSON.stringify(). Then you will be able to see the result data as object. You can assign the data to a variable for further operations

Comment: Since you already have `dataType: "json",` so  `JSON.stringify().` not needed at all

Comment: i've tried to, it didn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a grammatical error in a word "sucess", the correct word is "success"

```
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "./data.php",
      dataType: "json",
      sucess: function (data){ // Here -> success
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));

      }
    });
```